How to calculate density altitude using this chart?
I am trying to use the chart to calculate the density altitude. The question is : (Refer to figure 8 in your Test Guide book) If the current temperature is 90°F, PA 2000’ and altimeter is 29.70, what is the density altitude?
I did 2000' plus 205 since that is the pressure altitude convertor factor. 29.70 is 205 on the chart.
So I used 2205 and went on the chart and used 90 Fahrenheit and then got an answer of 4,600 feet. I feel like I am doing something wrong like there is an additional calculation before doing it.


If you are on a pressure altitude of 2000 ft, that is already assuming a standard altimeter setting of 29.92".
First you find the intersection of the line representing 2000 ft pressure altitude and 90°F. From there you read the approximate density altitude on the vertical axis. This will get you to ~4400 ft.

If your barometric altitude were 2000 ft at an altimeter setting of 29.70", then you would first need to calculate your pressure altitude. This would be done using the table on the right. The correction value of 205 needs to be added to the barometric altitude to convert to a standard setting of 29.92". This would yield a pressure altitude of 2205 ft.
Now using the density altitude chart again, you would find a density altitude of approximately 4600 ft.

Thank you so much! I guess I was heading in the right direction.
